# Prove $<x, f'(x) \geq pf(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let f: A →ℝ, where A ⊆ ℝn is an open. We will say that f is homogeneous
of grade **p** over A if

f (tx) = t^(p).f(x)

for each **t** ∈ ℝ and x ∈ A for which    **tx ∈ A**. If such a function is differentiable
at x ∈ A, prove that

```
<x, f'(x) > = pf(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dt} f(tx) = \frac{d}{dt} t^{p} f(x)$
Gives $pt^{p-1} f(x) = \langle x , \nabla f (tx) \rangle$

Setting t = 1 gives $pf(x) = \langle x, \nabla f(x) \rangle $

Comment: For any x in A, defining $g(t) = f(tx)$ is possible (in a small enough neighbourhood of x, that is, on $t \in (1 - \epsilon , 1+\epsilon)$ ) because A is open.

Comment: ∇ Is the key!   Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many things you need to have more clarifications in your statement. However, in my opinion, the solution does not vary much.
Roughly speaking, we have:
$f(x+tx)= f(x)+ < \nabla f(x), tx>+ o( tx)$ when $t \longrightarrow 0$
which combines with homogenous fact given, we deduce:
$ \left[ \frac{(t+1)^p-1}{t} \right]f(x) = < \nabla f(x), x> +o(x)$
Hence, we're done.
Surely, this one is not a rigorous solution but i think the necessary elements are all presented.